# MPVolumnView ShowVolumeView Animation

Tags: animation, mpvolumeview

In my code ,I need to hide the slider by click ,then show it by click again,but when it show ,i see an animation like the slider width from 0 to its width,may anyone tell me how to show the slider without an animation?